# How to set charactor encoding to UTF-8 in Jasper version 6.20.0 or 6.20.6 in Java Spring boot

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Spring boot version: 3.1.5
Java version: 21
Jasper version: 6.20.0 or 6.20.6

I am trying to convert the .jrPrint file to PDF and PDFA by using Jasper and these are my dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.20.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and setEncoding Method isn't available to use. Perhaps it doesn't exist. And I tried to use JRPdfExporter and set its parameter, so the JRExporterParameter is deprecated.

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(
                new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new FileOutputStream(new File(pdfOutputPath))));

Map<JRExporterParameter, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("net.sf.jasperreports.export.character.encoding", "UTF-8");
exporter.setParameters(parameters);
```